# Access Current System Date with Custom format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdate

Which method will i use for print (MM-DD-YYYY) format of date ? for Ex 03-26-2012

i have been try this code but that is give me like 03/26/12

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];    

    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
    [dateFormatter release];
    NSLog(@"format:%@",currentTime);
```

can i access only Day and month from current date ??

Comment: can u retrive the digit of the month or name of the month?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];   

NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"format:%@",currentTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using setDateStyle you can use setDateFormat:

[formatter setDateFormat:@"mm-dd-yyyy"];

Google "strftime formatting" for all the formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is useful to find out the days months calculates.

```
    NSDateComponents *comp=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 



    monthDigits=comp.month;
```

This thinks is very helping to you.